# Specifying screen width as a "dynamic" constant

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView class I'm integrating into a project. I plan to add `MySubView` to `MyViewController`. There's a constant class where the screen width is hard-coded as follows:

**`MySubviewConstants.h`**

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 300.0f
```

I'd like to define this constant as the width of the subview of the device it's running on, not a hard-coded number. I think this should be an easy 25 pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will get the actual device's screen width:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
```

Or perhaps using a variant of:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].view convertRect:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] fromView:nil].size
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to do this in a subview, which is what's tripping me up. `MyViewController` has `MySubview`. When `drawMySubview` is called in `mySubView` class, I want the constant that's defined in `mySubviewConstants` to return the size of the view on `myViewController`

Comment: Ok. So just to check, the subview is not the same width as the device? Which bit is specifically tripping you up? Are you getting errors?

Comment: The subview is not the same width as the device. The easy fix would be to make it the same width, but I'd like to learn how to get the width of just the subview.